# Using SNMP on php project

Tags: php, snmp

My question if it's possible and useful to use SNMP on php, for monitoring the system, I read something about snmpwalk, but I'm not sure if it would do what O'm looking for.

I Need to make a system to manage around thousand PCs, for example I need to find online PCs, and retrieve some information's from PCs, without overload on the mysql server, can this be done or not? What do you advise?

Comment: What exactly do you want to monitor? SNMP does not give you all the stats by default, unless you configure 1000+ devices to give you exactly what you want in SNMP response.

Comment: I just need to monitor desktops , and find out online pc's , so how can i configure remote pc's to send status to the server , i read something about MIB and OID but i doesn't know how to catch the MIB for the desktop , and what's the configuration  required on both server and desktop, also do i need to open ports for that on routers , or it's secure port and open by default ?

Comment: Most devices disable SNMP to prevent information leak. It would be too easy to scan the internet and find devices that are vulnerable to exploits if it wasn't. Also, since it uses UDP, it is possible to do an amplified DDOS attack if your SNMP is exposed to public(SNMP reflector attack). There are a couple guides on how to enable SNMP service in windows, but if your devices have static IPs, or if you are on the same subnet and just care about devices being up or down you can either PING them, or dump your ARP tables and look for mac addresses.